# Rails 3 Migration: Autoincrement on (Non-Primary-Key) Column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking for a way to create a column that autoincrements the way the automatic :id column does. I could probably handle this somehow in the model, but that seems kludgey. I haven't found anything in stock Rails 3 that handles this; are there gems available that might handle this? I'm surprised it's not already an option, since Rails handles this behavior for primary key columns.

Comment: Primary key columns auto increment because of the database itself, MySQL or whichever DBMS your using will increment the primary key with each new record. Why do you need another incrementing column?

Comment: Well if you aren't planning on changing databases, you could always simply use 'execute' in a migration to add another sequence/auto-incrementing field in raw SQL. However, if you're going to end up with 2 columns that are both auto-incrementing, aren't they really the same column? I realize that a purist would at this point beat me over the head, but...

Answer (score 1):

Normally auto-incrementing columns are implemented using database sequences. The advantage of using a sequence over calculating the next increment, is that getting the next value from a sequence is atomic. So if you have multiple processes creating new elements, the sequence will make sure your numbers are really unique.

Sequences can be used in postgresql, oracle, mysql, ...

How to implement this, if you are using postgres for instance:

- select the next value from the sequence:

  `Integer(Operator.connection.select_value("SELECT nextval('#{sequence_name}')"))`
- create a sequence:

  `Operator.connection.execute("CREATE sequence #{sequence_name}")`
- set the start-value of a sequence :

  ```
  Operator.connection.execute("SELECT setval('#{sequence_name}', #{new_start_serial})")
  ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you really think you need this you could create a before_create filter in the model to check the last record attribute value and add 1 to it. Feels hacking though.

Comment: I agree -- it seems hackish. As to why I'd need such a thing: autoincrement isn't just for primary keys, in the DB world. In this case, I'm adding a series of steps, and don't really like having to explicitly number them, when Rails could do it for me. I may need to write this gem.