# Ruby generate unique integer for use as a primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to generate a unique integer that will be assigned to the id field within a rails app. What is the best way of doing this. (using the usual auto increment is not an option and it has to be an integer.)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126065/rails-3-migration-autoincrement-on-non-primary-key-column

Comment: Just out of curiosity I have to ask why autoincrement is not acceptable?

Answer (score 24):

Ruby 1.9 has [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) version 4 generation included in module [SecureRandom](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/securerandom/1.9.3/SecureRandom):

```
> require 'securerandom'
 => true
> SecureRandom.uuid
 => "4b3a56db-4906-4a44-a262-975d80c88195" 
> SecureRandom.uuid.gsub("-", "").hex
 => 56667719780883163491780810954791777167
```

A bit lengthy, but unique for sure.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `securerandom`'s `.random_number()` method if you don't want to do the `gsub` bit:

```
SecureRandom.random_number(100000000000000000000000000000)
```

https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/securerandom/1.9.3/SecureRandom#random_number-class_method

Comment: Yeah I think SecureRandom didn't have that back in 2011.

Comment: Lol probably should have paid attention to when the year was...didn’t need to bump this thread  that doc link is from the Ruby version you referenced though ‍♂️

Answer (score -2):

I don't understand why you can't use auto increment, but have you considered using a random number?

```
id = rand(1000000)
while(Post.find(id) != nil)
  id = rand(1000000)
end
```

Comment: The solution I used in the end was

    self.id = "#{Time.now.year}#{Time.now.to_i}#{Time.now.usec.to_s[0..2]}".to_i

If anyone can think of any issues with this, please let me know.

Comment: This solution is victim of concurrent race. Under hiload different instances of your applications can generate same integers. Good example is here http://bit.ly/nKqrq3 (MongoDB ObjectID): this is a 12-byte value consisting of a 4-byte timestamp, a 3-byte machine id, a 2-byte process id, and a 3-byte counter.